# Providing Example that independence of events $A, B$ is dependent on Probability measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, independence

I have just started probability and I am rather confused at the notion of probability measure $P$ and how it essentially differs from the distribution of a random variable $X$ under $P$

First, I need an explanation:

> In most textbooks, it is stated for a random variable $X$ from a
>   Probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ to an event space
>   $(\Omega',\mathcal{F}')$ then $P'(A'):=P_{X}(A')=P(X^{-1}A')$ is a
>   probability measure, namely the distribution of a random variable $X$
>   under $P$. But how is this any different from the original Probability
>   measure $P: \mathcal{F} \to [0,1], A \mapsto P(A)$, which is simply
>   mapping subsets of $\Omega$ onto $[0,1]$. Is it a different $P'$
>   probability measure altogether? I mean surely it depends on the map of
>   our previous probability measure $P$? What is the intuition behind
>   this rather opaque version of defining the probability with respect to
>   a random variable?

My example for independence:

Let there be $3$ $6-$sided dice with each dice taking on either colour blue, green or red.

Let event $A:=$ the dice selected is red.

and event $B:=$ the dice selected and then thrown shows $2$.

Let's then take $2$ probability measures $P, Q$. We set $P$ equal to uniform distribution.

It follows that $P(A \cap B) = \frac{1}{6 \times 3}=\frac{1}{18}$

and $P(A) \times P(B)=\frac{1}{3} * \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{18}$, so $A, B$ are naturally independent.

Now I am attempting to find a **probability measure** $Q$ such that:

$Q(A \cap B) \neq Q(A) \times Q(B)$

My idea: perhaps $Q(C)=\frac{2|\Omega|-|C|}{|\Omega|}$. But how can I be sure that it is $\sigma-$additive, it is clearly "normed" as $Q(\Omega)=1$.

$Q(A \cap B)= \frac{2 \times 18-1}{18}>1$, which is not true for  a probaility measure, right? Is my example wrong? Can you provide me with more intuitive examples?

Comment: You have 3 dice but then talk about "the dice thrown is red"?

Comment: The dice that is selected rather

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest example might be when $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $\mathcal F=2^\Omega$, $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{1,3\}$.

Then, the events $A$ and $B$ are independent under the uniform measure $P$ but not under the measure $Q$ defined by $Q(\{1\})=\frac12$ and $Q(\{2\})=Q(\{3\})=Q(\{4\})=\frac16$.

---

Regarding the explanation you demand, simply note that, in the context you describe, $P$ is a measure on $\mathcal F$ while $P'=P_X$ is a measure on $\mathcal F'$. The most common case might be when $(\Omega',\mathcal F')=(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ and $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$. Then the distribution of $X$ is a measure on the sigma-algebra $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ on the target set $\mathbb R$, and certainly not a measure on the sigma-algebra $\mathcal F$ on the source set $\Omega$.

To sum up, in most cases, $P$ and $P'$ are probability measures on different spaces, hence one definitely cannot use one for the other.

Comment: But $P'$ as probability measure relies on $P$ to get its "mapping" or functional definition, i.e. $P'(A)$ is still dependent on $P$ as $P'(A)=P(X^{-1}A)$

Comment: Yes, $P'=P_X$ depends on $P$ and on $X$, as the notation suggests. Why is this a problem?

Comment: I just sometimes find it awkward that we refer to a probability measure $P$ on $\mathcal{F}$ but we then define a probability measure $P'$ which is the distribution of $X$ under $P$ that is essentially the same probability measure $P$ but just on a different $\sigma-$algebra, namely $\mathcal{F'}$

Comment: Can I say: the probability measure $P$ can also be described as the distribution of $X$ under $P$, where $X=Id_{\Omega}$?

Comment: Yes, if $\Omega=\Omega'$, $\mathcal F=\mathcal F'$ and $X=\mathrm{Id}_\Omega$, then $P_X=P$. Focussing on this specific case could be detrimental to your understanding though, especially since you seem to believe it describes the typical situation. For example, the assertion that "the distribution of X under P (...) is essentially the same probability measure P but just on a different σ−algebra" is plainly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

We can take our probability space to be $\Omega = \{b,g,r\}\times \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$ Define $Q(\{(r,1)\}) = 1/36,$ $ Q(\{(r,2)\}) = 1/12,$ and $Q(\{(x,y)\}) = 1/18$ for all other $(x,y)\in \Omega.$ For any $E\subset \Omega,$ we then set

$$Q(E)= \sum_{(x,y)\in E}Q(\{(x,y)\}).$$

Then $Q$ is a probability measure on $\Omega.$

But note $Q(A)=1/3$ and

$$Q(B)= Q(\{(b,2),(g,2),(r,2)\}) = 1/18+1/18+1/12=7/36.$$

However

$$Q(A\cap B) = Q(\{(r,2)\}) = 1/12 \ne Q(A)\cdot Q(B) =(1/3)\cdot(7/36).$$